# full width div by small description text css responsive

Tags: css, text, responsive-design, width

i like to width: 100% for my text div. But i don't know why this not working.

So if i have small description text i have not full width by my list div and if i have long description text so i have 100% width div.

Here my screeny Problem:

[image]

[DEMO SITE](http://davis-design.de/marktadresse/nordrhein-westfalen.html)

Here my HTML:

```
<div class="columns events_list_even margin_padding_clean">
                            <div class="event_list_abstand">
                            <div class="two columns padding_right_left_clean">
                            <div class="date-list"><i class="fa fa-calendar fa-lg" style="margin-right: 10px"></i>Mo. 14.04.2014 </div>
                    <img src="http://www.davis-design.de/marktadresse/files/floh_troedel_jahrmarkt.png" class="category_icon">
                    <img src="http://www.davis-design.de/marktadresse/layout/images/veranstaltung_halbwegs_ueberdachung.png" class="roof">
                     </div>
                     <div class="ten columns margin_bottom_clean padding_right_left_clean">
                     <a href="/marktadresse/niedersachsen.html?veranstaltung=Abendmarkt+Osnabrueck%7E1X4JxCOwhDpD4Oj5ch%7E14.04.2014"><h2 class="date-ueberschrift" style="border-bottom: none;">Abendmarkt Osnabrueck</h2></a>
                     <div class="date-info"> Albrechtstraße 15 | 49076 Osnabrück |
                       Floh-, Trödel- &amp; Jahrmarkt</div>
                      <p class="margin_bottom_clean">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam ...</p></div></div></div>
```

Comment: could u please share ur css

Comment: @fidelcastro i post my DEMO Site you can test it on firebug or google developer tool. CSS is to much code ^^

Comment: ok dave i found solution for u check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Please check image here]Add "width:100%" in your class(event_list_abstand).

Comment: i update my question. Hope you understand my problem better :)

Comment: i need this format if i have long description text by small description text.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your css

```
div.columns.events_list_even.margin_padding_clean {
width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: thx for your tipp. But i need this: if have small discreption text <p>blubblub</p> in the div that the width 100%

Answer (score 0):

```
columns {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Make the above mentioned changes in the responsive.css at line number 5,to get the div with full width

Comment: thx for your answer.  
i update my question. Hope you understand my problem better :)

Answer (score 0):

According to your CSS, to target only the white and grey boxes, try:

```
.loop-posts .events_list_even{
   width:100%;
}
```

Comment: thx for your answer. 
i update my question. Hope you understand my problem better :)